# Ubuntu Touch RC version 42 bricked my Nexus 4

Tags: ubuntu-touch

I have been running a Nexus 4 with Ubuntu Touch (mako) rc (http://system-image.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-touch/rc/ubuntu/mako/) for about the last month. It's really great overall.

This morning I got a notification that an update to the Ubuntu Touch was available. "Sweet!" I thought, and went ahead and clicked update. Phone said it needed to restart to install update.

After it restarted, I saw the Ubuntu progress bar increasing. I left the phone and came back half an hour later to a backlit black screen. Phone didn't respond so I restarted holding down the power button.

Now the phone boots through the Google boot screen then into the ubuntu splash screen with the dots. It cycles through the dots a few times then screen goes black (still backlit). Backlighting responds to me clicking the screen lock and unlock (power) button. Other than that it does nothing.

I've tried to attach to my laptop (ubuntu gnome 16.10). Nautilus sees the device but when i click on it to mount it I get the error

```
Unable to access "Nexus 4"
Unable to open MTP device '[usb:003,006]'
```

The phone does still boot into recovery without a problem. Unforunately I don't have a backup to restore to (doh!).

What can I do to try and get this phone working again?

**Edit**: I can interact with the phone over `adb`. Ran:

```
$ adb devices
$ adb shell
```

which has given me the `phablet@ubuntu-phablet:` prompt. I can see stuff in my home directory which is nice.

**Edit 2**: While my phone has just been sitting on my desk, it did start ringing at one point. So it is still receiving calls. But the screen is blank so I couldn't answer the call.

Comment: Your title is about OTA 42. Isn't your question about OTA 14?

Comment: I had trouble with the version 42 update (http://system-image.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-touch/rc/ubuntu/mako/). Is that not considered OTA 42? If I've used the wrong nomenclature I will be happy to modify the title of the question

Comment: I think your Image is could be called RC version 42. Later on it will become an RC-Proposed version and then a Stable version which will then be called OTA 14.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to be just a UI failure in this update. So, when adb works, you can reflash the device e.g. via the ubuntu-device-flash tool keeping your personal data (use -h for documentation).

Edit: Found this fortunely in the Landing team: https://lists.launchpad.net/ubuntu-phone/msg22825.html
It's about the Meizu Pro5 having the same problem. Seems to be a harder problem. Good luck :)

Comment: Thanks Bjarne. Your answer helped me. Reflashing to a previous version did the trick. After connecting to device (booted device into Ubuntu, not recovery), i issued `ubuntu-device-flash --revision=41 touch --channel=ubuntu-touch/rc/ubuntu` from my laptop, which flashed the phone to the previous version of UT. Device booted up perfectly after that with all my data intact.